# I can't play sound on click in a drum machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a simple react drum machine from freecodecamp.

I want to render 9 drumpads and play sound on click.

Edit: I can now render all keys but still have problems with the function for playing the sounds for each key on click.
I used querySelector now but it still doesn't work. I have no idea how to fix it.

```
import * as React from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";
import * as ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@17.0.1";

 

function DrumPad() {
  const pads = [
    {
      key: "Q",
      id: "Heat-1",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3"
    },
    {
      key: "W",
      id: "Heat-2",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3"
    },
    {
      key: "E",
      id: "Heat-3",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3"
    },
    {
      key: "A",
      id: "Heat-4",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3"
    },
    {
      key: "S",
      id: "Clap",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3"
    },
    {
      key: "D",
      id: "Open-HH",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3"
    },
    {
      key: "Z",
      id: "Kick-n-Hat",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3"
    },
    {
      key: "X",
      id: "Kick",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3"
    },
    {
      key: "C",
      id: "Closed-HH",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      {pads.map((pad) => (
        <div
          key={pad.id}
          className="drum-pad"
          id={pad.id}
          onclick={function () {
            const sound = document.querySelector("audio[id=" + pad.key + "]");
            sound.play();
          }}
        >
          {pad.key}
          <audio id={pad.key} src={pad.url} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="drum-machine">
        <DrumPad />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: id="audio" is not unique as it is rn

Comment: Don't' use `getElementById` in react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are returning within a for loop, the component will return during the first iteration of the loop which means the function call will end. This is why only one key is rendered.

In React.js we usually do `array.map()` instead of for loops. Something like:

```js
function DrumPad() {
  const pads = [
    {
      key: "Q",
      id: "Heat-1",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3",
    },
    {
      key: "W",
      id: "Heat-2",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-2.mp3",
    },
    {
      key: "E",
      id: "Heat-3",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-3.mp3",
    },
    {
      key: "A",
      id: "Heat-4",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-4_1.mp3",
    },
    {
      key: "S",
      id: "Clap",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-6.mp3",
    },
    {
      key: "D",
      id: "Open-HH",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Dsc_Oh.mp3",
    },
    {
      key: "Z",
      id: "Kick-n-Hat",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Kick_n_Hat.mp3",
    },
    {
      key: "X",
      id: "Kick",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/RP4_KICK_1.mp3",
    },
    {
      key: "C",
      id: "Closed-HH",
      url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Cev_H2.mp3",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div id="drum-pad-grid">
      {pads.map((pad) => (
        <div
          key={pad.id}
          className="drum-pad"
          id={pad.id}
          onClick={() => {
            const audio = new Audio(pad.url);
            audio.play();
          }}
        >
          {pad.key}
        </div>
      ))}{" "}
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render( 
  <DrumPad /> ,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
#drum-pad-grid {
  max-width: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.drum-pad {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: gainsboro
}

.drum-pad:active {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: still has a huge flaw with ids

Comment: Fixed my snippet. I did remove `audio` element and created audio programatically.

Comment: I found my mistake. it was the attribute onclick. thar should be onClick.